# How to receive POST request from Javascript in Python CGI script?

Tags: javascript, python, request, cgi

I have a website with a big form. When I first made the website, I was using a GET request to send the form values to a Python CGI script (using the JavaScript fetch function). In the Python script, I could read the data with `parameters = cgi.FieldStorage()`.

Since a GET request has a limited payload size, I had to switch to a POST request because that request type has no limit.

I changed my JavaScript fetch function to the following to make a POST request:

```
  fetch('../../cgi-bin/saveFormAnswers.py', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    }
  })
    .then(antwoord => antwoord.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Return data Python:")
      console.log(data);
    }
    );
```

However, I can't seem to get the data in the Python CGI script. `cgi.FieldStorage()` doesn't work anymore. How do I get the POST payload in the Python script and how do I send a (JSON) dictionary back as a response to the POST request?

I'm not using any frameworks like Flask.

EDIT: I came to the conclusion it's related to the JavaScript code and that `cgi.FieldStorage()` should work. Instead of letting JavaScript do the POST request, I set up the POST request directly in the HTML form which worked just fine without any issues. I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong with my JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using `sys.stdin` instead of `cgi.FieldStorage()`.

```
data = ""

if int(os.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0)) != 0:

    for i in range(int(os.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))):
        data += sys.stdin.read(1)
```